# plant fossil or trace of water?

Tags: fossils

I've found this rock at the altitude of 2500 meters.
Is it a plant fossil or trace of water?
[image]

Comment: Looks like manganese dendrites: https://woostergeologists.scotblogs.wooster.edu/2013/01/20/woosters-pseudofossil-of-the-week-manganese-dendrites-from-the-germany/

Comment: To those voting to close: it's true that the question lacks details, but fossil identification is on topic.